# Notarization of install4j packages for macOS 10.14+

Tags: java, macos, install4j, macos-mojave

I'm still on install4j 6 and when I upload the dmg file of our last release for notarization I get a message that *the executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled*. We build on a Windows server. The app is signed and we use install4j to do all signing automatically and Java 8 is included. It seems that users can install our old release on Mojave but for the next release in January I want to make sure everything is in order. Is notarization required? Does install4j 7.0.8 have support for notarization and *hardened runtime*? Can we do that on Windows or would we have to do it on macOS 10.14 Mojave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 7.0.8 there is no support for notarized signatures. We plan to look at that feature for install4j 8.

However, notarized signatures are not required for macOS 10.14.

Answer (score 0):

The notarisation process requires at least some of the build to be run on a mac because it uses altool and stapler, both of which are bundled with Xcode.  I've written a bash script that automates the process, but it starts with a zip file containing the app bundle, not the dmg.  You're welcome to the script if running it on a mac is feasible for you.

Comment: If you have such a script, I would be very grateful if you could post it or arrange to send it to me.  I have been trying to follow the process in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112078/how-to-upload-dmg-file-for-notarization-in-xcode, but having lots of trouble, mostly because I don't really have a clue as to what names go with what.

Comment: Hi Fred, sure thing:  https://seanreilly.com/build_mac_dmg It depends upon a couple of other minor scripts, including build_settings which basically sets environment variables and puts all the jar files in a folder.  The script invokes an ant task (https://github.com/TheInfiniteKind/appbundler) to build the app bundle from a jdk that you specify and ideally create yourself using jlink.  So I don't end up using install4j for my mac versions but do use it for windows and linux.