# macOS code sign and notarize .app and .dmg for distribution

Tags: macos, code-signing, notarize

I have a simple question, but I could not find an exhaustive answer. We have an .app that we distribute (download) as a .dmg. We can code-sign and notarise without problems using the Terminal. Everything works fine. However, we have doubts about the right thing that needs to be code signed and notarised: the app, the image or both?

As for now, we followed this:

- .app is code signed and .app is notarised
- notarised .app is inserted in .dmg
- the .dmg as it is is loaded to our server for deployment

However, I am not sure this is the right way. Should instead be like this?

- .app is code signed
- code signed .app is inserted in .dmg
- the .dmg is code signed too and notarised, and loaded to server

Or even:
+ .app is code signed and .app is notarised
+ notarised .app is inserted in .dmg
+ the .dmg is code signed too and notarised, and loaded to server

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you want to codesign the `.dmg` then do it the second way; I'm not sure about the notarizing of the `.dmg`, because you'd typically do that on your `.app`.

Comment: Cheers. But it is not a question of what I want, the question is what Apple wants us to do so that the user's experience in installing the app is the best possible one. Unfortunately, I have not found any official guideline about this very point.

Comment: If the first way works for you, then why change it? However, it is sufficient to sign the .app, and sign and notarize the .dmg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112078/how-to-upload-dmg-file-for-notarization-in-xcode/53121755#53121755

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the procedure:

1. build the app and `codesign` all binaries in it.
2. zip the `.app`
3. notarize the `.zip` file
4. staple the `.app` after notarization succeeds
5. make the `.dmg` from the notarized and stapled `.app`
6. notarize and staple the `.dmg`