# How to notarize a Java app bundled in .dmg created by Install4j?

Tags: macos, install4j

I need to notarize a Java app that is bundled by Install4J.

At the end of the process I get:
.dmg: rejected (the code is valid but does not seem to be an app)

It seems I need to sign items within .dmg according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112078/how-to-upload-dmg-file-for-notarization-in-xcode) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101626/how-to-notarize-an-app-bundle-containing-helpers-embedded-in-it).

I am uncertain how this signing relates to that of made by install4j.
Do I need to use a Code Signing Identity used by install4j or my own to pass to 's' option?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with install4j 7.x, but it is going to be supported directly in install4j 8.x, to be released this summer.

Comment: My question is not about how to do notarization with install4j.

Comment: You cannot notarize a DMG that has been created by install4j 7.x.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.